# Get date of a live event using the Vimeo API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a project that involves live events which are hosted using Vimeo.

I know we can grab the videos on Vimeo along with their details using:

```
$response = $vimeo->request('/me/videos', array('name' => 'video_name'), 'GET');
```

This works great and returns all our videos, both videos and future events.

However, I can not find the date that the event is set to take place within the payload returned by Vimeo. It returns the following dates, none of which is the date the event will take place (which is 3 months from now):

```
  "created_time" => "2019-12-10T11:03:13+00:00"
  "modified_time" => "2019-12-10T12:08:11+00:00"
  "release_time" => "2019-12-10T11:03:13+00:00"
```

The date the event is set to take place is included within the iframe that is returned in the payload, however it does not include the year and therefore it is essentially useless for what we need.

I was wondering if anyone with more experience using the Vimeo API would be able to point me in the right direction with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public Vimeo API doesn't currently support Vimeo Live events, so the API won't return any metadata specific to Live events, such as the scheduled broadcast date/time.